# How to handle cpu intensive operations in google app engine server?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron

I have cron job that triggers an api in my node.js server hosted in google app engine. This route iterates over an array of 800 objects and for each object we perform various api calls to db and some lambda functions. Currently we are using an F4 instance class and I could see the cpu utilization is high during this job and before when we had more objects, there were incidents where it failed half-way. Is there anything I can do to make sure it is failure-resistent as well as not a costlier solution.

This is the code that we had earlier without the cron job and it is not performant and takes a lot of time to complete. Few of them are db calls and some are lambda calls. Any suggestion on improving it without cron job also will be appreciated! Thanks

```
async processEvals() {
    try {
      const { db } = await require("../firestore/firestore");
      let accessToken = await getAccessToken();
      let headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      };
      let allTeamParams = { teamId: "all","department": CONSTANTS.DEPARTMENT }
      let allTeamResponse = await axios.post(CONSTANTS.TEAMSENDPOINT, allTeamParams,{ headers: headers });
      let teams_data = await this.getActiveTeams(allTeamResponse);
      this.qaRequirements = await this.getQARequirements();

      for (let team_info of teams_data) {
        console.log(`LEAD ${team_info.lead.login_email}  STARTS`);
        let sampleListByAgent = await getSamplesByTeam(team_info.lead.members);
        let evaluators_info = await this.getEvaluatorInfo(
          team_info.lead.contact_id,team_info.lead.login_email
        );
        this.qaCursor = 0;
        for (let staff_info of team_info.lead.members) {
          if(isSeniorLead(staff_info.position) || isLead(staff_info.position)){
            continue;
          }
          let ctr_records =
            sampleListByAgent[
              getValidLogin(staff_info.login_email.split("@")[0])
            ];
          let resultsArray = ctr_records;
          for (let ctr_record of resultsArray) {
            let evaluator = await this.getEvaluator(
              evaluators_info[resultsArray.indexOf(ctr_record)],
              team_info.lead
            );
            let eval_obj = createEvalObj(staff_info, team_info, evaluator, ctr_record);
            await db
              .collection(CONSTANTS.EVALS_TABLE)
              .add(eval_obj)
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log("err  ", err);
              });
          }
        }
        console.log(`LEAD ${team_info.lead.login_email}  ENDS`);
      }
      return "evaluations successful";
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Split this out into multiple jobs. Have cron call your 'fan-out' job, which launches a Google Cloud Task for each element. Each google cloud task then is just responsible for a single element (and even this step could get broken out into several google cloud tasks).  Now if there is a failure, then only that part has to be restarted.

Also look into Google Dataflow, to convert this into a map-reduce style job. It can handle processing large scales of data.

Comment: Thanks on the thought @alex , can you please elaborate on the map-reduce part? or maybe some resources that can help. My backend is node.js by the way

Comment: Sure. Map reduce paradigm for organizing a work flow into a bunch of small functions that can be executed by separate works allowing great scalability. Google Dataflow is a managed version of Apache beam, which follows that paradigm. Here is a good doc for that: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/ These workers are different from your webserver/GAE, so it doesn't matter what you're doing on GAE. However, Dataflow/Beam doesnt support javascript yet. You'd have to use one of the supported languages if you go that route.

Comment: Hello @alex , I've updated the code in the question. Would you be able to provide some suggestion?

Comment: change this for loop `for (let team_info of teams_data) {` to launch a task https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks#node.js and then move the code inside of that for loop into a task handler https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#node.js This will parallelize the operation

Comment: Hi @alex , More when I look into the solution I realized that in the problem we have a dependency between each array element. For each iteration, `getQARequirements ` is called which holds the total number of qa that are yet to be assigned and the value changes for each iteration(number gets deducted for each iteration). How do I handle this dependent scenario? Any idea on how to make it more optimized?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, the answers you're going to get will be high level and general in nature.

1. If you're retrieving your objects from a file, you might want to consider not reading the entire thing into memory first  i.e. read from a stream (see [this article](https://flaviocopes.com/node-reading-files/) for an explanation and example code). This reduces your memory consumption
2. You should also check if it's possible to make some of your calls asynchronous. This way, you can continue executing other parts of your code while waiting for response to the asynchronous calls you've made. This might speed up the overall program execution which means less execution time.
3. Also check if some of your calls can be made in batches instead of one by one in a loop (some APIs including some of Google's accept array of objects in addition to single objects).

Comment: Thanks on the thoughts! The input is an array of json objects which is fetched from an api. Can you please tell me more on batch processing? Like how would it be good for app engine performance or maybe some resources on the same that I can refer

Comment: Without details, it is difficult to tell, but [Cloud Run Jobs][1] might be a good fit, as it has many of the benefits of serverless, but is designed for recurring/batch workloads.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run#jobs

Comment: @SharonShelton: Some of the Google APIs allow you to make calls in a batch (pass in an array). E.g. to read from datastore given a set of keys, you can pass in the keys as an array instead of looping one by one. You should check if the APIs you're accessing supports that

Comment: One more question, doesn't making the code asynchronous overloads the cpu? Like if all the operations are taking place at the same time

Comment: Not necessarily. Everything depends on your code (how it's structured, what endpoints you're calling, etc). You'll have to look at your code and see if it makes sense making asynchronous calls

Comment: I've updated the code in the question. Will you be able to provide some suggestion on the same?